# How to update data in a Many-to-Many linking table?

Tags: database, relational-database

For simplicity’s sake lets assume there’s a Post table and a Tags table (not the actual use case but this will keep it simple)

**posts Table**

```
id |  title
--------------------------------
1  |  Random Text Here
2  |  Another Post About Stuff
```

**tags Table**

```
id | tag
--------------------------------
1  | javascript
2  | node
3  | unrelated-thing
```

**posts_tags table**

```
id| post_id | tag_id
--------------------------------
1 | 1       | 1
2 | 1       | 2
3 | 1       | 3
4 | 2       | 2
```

A Post can have many Tags and a single Tag could be associated with many Posts.

**Web App Assumptions** Lets pretend adding/removing a Tag doesn't trigger a single aysnchronous action within the web app against the linking table. 
 Instead the user would edit the Post (adding or removing any tags already created) then hit Save.  The web app would submit JSON including an array of Tags ids associated with the Post to the server which would then process the update request in the code.

For example, `post_id=1` is submitted with only `tag_id=[1,2]` so `tag=3` needs to be removed as an association in the linking table.

If a Post or a Tag is deleted, I'd have an ON DELETE CASCADE set on

- posts_tags.post_id
- posts_tags.tag_id

But what is the best way to update the linking table data in the instance of updating the tags associated with a post?

**Option 1:**

- Get all the Post-Tags for the edited Post  `SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE post_id = 1`
- Determine which tags have been added (and INSERT into linking table)
- Determine which tags have been removed (and DELETE from linking table)

**Option 2:**

- Delete ALL tags with the post_id in the linking table
- Insert all submitted tags into the linking table

**Option 3:**

- Something I'm not thinking about :)

Would Option 2 have a bigger performance impact on indexes as the table grows?

EDIT:

- For clarity, the actual Post and Tag data isn't changed or removed.  This is purely about Updating a post's associated tags
- The database I'm using is PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: You can make a trigger he is call automatically if you put keywords like `AFTER INSERT UPDATE DELETE`. In this case when you delete a row the other row with the same id is deleted in cascade. You do the trigger once then he do the job for you ^^

Comment: I'm not sure how that would solve it?

Data isn't actually inserted or updated in my example scenario in either posts or tags tables.  It's more about updating the associated ids within the linking table (posts_tags) when a Post is updated and a different selection of tags is associated with that Post.

Comment: I gave you all the possibilities but if you want to make that an `AFTER UPDATE`, you can. The most important in a trigger, it is the content well to put that you want the identifier to be updated on all the other tables associated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 would be fine from a performance point of view - much better than option 1, because you have a single operation to delete the old associations, and then a bunch on insert statements. In option 1, you have more queries (your first query to retrieve the associations, and then the deletes if applicable).

As long as your table has an index on post_id, then `delete * from posts_tags where post_id = ?` will be lightning fast, even on a huge table.

There is an alternative...

**posts_tags table**

```
id| post_id | tag_id | version_id
--------------------------------
1 | 1       | 1      | 0
2 | 1       | 2      | 0
3 | 1       | 3      | 1
4 | 2       | 2      | 0
5 | 1       | 1      | 2
6 | 1       | 3      | 2
```

In this case, you use a versioning mechanism to determine the "current" associations (max(version_id)), so you never have to delete anything - you just insert new rows.

In practice, this is probably no faster, but it does save you that "delete" query.